# How to use apply instead of for-loop to check every column in every row

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm trying to check for every row in my data.table if there are certain elements ( which i declare as 1 if there is). If there are, i would want to output a new column that shows the value (a probability of the element happening) referenced from another data.table.

This is the input

```
structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), C = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), D = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

The tables which i used to reference to get the probabilities

Table Pyxixj

```
    A   B   C   D
 A  0   0   0   0
 B  0   0   0   0
 C  0   0   0   0.001804403
 D  0   0   0.001804403 0
```

Table Pyxi

```
A   0
B   0
C   0.00086701
D   0.000250439
```

This is the output

```
    A   B   C   D   prob
1   0   0   1   0   0.00086701
2   0   0   0   1   0.000250439
3   0   0   1   0   0.00086701
4   0   0   1   0   0.00086701
5   0   0   1   1   0.001804403
```

I have done it using the for-loop below but it takes 6hrs to run for about 1 million rows.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cnts2))
{
    if ((rowSums(cnts2 == "1", na.rm = TRUE) == 1)[i])
    {
        cnts2$prob[i] <- Pyxi[colnames(cnts2)[which(cnts2[i, ] == 1)]]
    }
    else
    {
        cnts2$prob[i] <- Pyxixj[colnames(cnts2)[which(cnts2[i, ] == 1)][1], colnames(cnts2)[which(cnts2[i, ] == 1)][2]]
    }
}
```

Have been trying `apply` but I have figured it out yet.

Comment: Could you use `dput` on those subsets of `Pyxixj` and `Pyxi` just to make it easier to reproduce them?

Comment: The data for those who want it
`cnts2<-matrix(c(0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,1), nrow=5,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(cnts2)<-c("A","B","C","D")
cnts2<-as.data.frame(cnts2)


Pyxixj<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0.001804403, 0,0,0.001804403,0), nrow=4,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(Pyxixj)<-c("A","B","C","D")
rownames(Pyxixj)<-c("A","B","C","D")

Pyxi<-matrix(c(0,0,0.00086701,0.000250439),nrow=4)
rownames(Pyxi)<-c("A","B","C","D")`

Comment: Have you tried parallel running with ForEach?

Comment: See also this post for a very good explanation of how to use apply(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980984/rewriting-loops-with-apply-functions?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that will be faster but may require more ram as it will create some very long data frames, I created a different Pyxixj dataframe as my solution doesn't require the other table.

The key to this solution is changing your cnts2 data frame into a form where the probabilities can be left joined on, and as such removing any need for loops or lapply

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
#probability data frame note use of X1
Pyxixj <- data.frame(X1=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
           matrix(data=sample(1:100, 16, replace=TRUE)/100, nrow= 4) ) %>% 
  setNames(c("X1", "A", "B", "C", "D"))


#Restructure the initial data frame
probmerge <-cnts2 %>%mutate(rowid= 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  gather(., key=column, value=yesno,-rowid) %>%
  filter(yesno==1) %>% group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(order=make.names(cumsum(yesno))) %>%
  spread(key=order, value=column) %>%
  mutate(X2=ifelse(is.na(X2),X1,X2)) %>%ungroup


#Gather your probability dataframe
Pyxixj <-Pyxixj %>% gather(key="X2", value=prob,-X1)

#join the two new dataframes
probmerge<-left_join(probmerge, Pyxixj, by=c("X1", "X2"))

#bind onto the orignial dataframe
cnts2 <- bind_cols(cnts2, select(probmerge, prob))
```

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly, now i just need to get the probability table Pyxixj combined right. Will try out how fast this takes later. Thanks!

Comment: If you make a symmetrical matrix where AA is the probability of just A it will work.  Or just make a three column matrix from the beginning, where the the columns are,  first letter,  second letter,  probability.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove look ups to table Pyxi from the for loop to cycle through more quickly

This makes use of R 's vectorisation of function application when looking up to Pyxi

```
 if (rowSums(cnts2 == "1", na.rm = TRUE) == 1)
    {
       cnts2$probs <- (Pyxi[rownames(Pyxi)=="A"]*cnts2$A
                  + Pyxi[rownames(Pyxi)=="B"]*cnts2$B
                  + Pyxi[rownames(Pyxi)=="C"]*cnts2$C
                  + Pyxi[rownames(Pyxi)=="D"]*cnts2$D)
     }
```

Then do the loop just where the row count is >1

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cnts2))
{
   if ((rowSums(cnts2 == "1", na.rm = TRUE) > 1)[i])
   {cnts2$prob[i] <- Pyxixj[colnames(cnts2)[which(cnts2[i, ] == 1)][1], 
    colnames(cnts2)[which(cnts2[i, ] == 1)][2]]
   }
}
```